# How do I reference a row immediately after it has been added to a table?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

This is PHP / CodeIgniter / MySQL

The only way I can think of is to do the insert ($this->db->insert(...)), and then immediatly after, run another query to find the record again.

I'm hoping there is something (which seems a bit more efficient to me) that returns the primary key (or something) of the newly added record.

Comment: I don't know about codeigniter, but usually there is a function like `lastInsertId()`

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id()` will give you the id of the last inserted row.

Comment: For CodeIgniter, it seems to be [`$this->db->insert_id()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: CodeIgniter is incredibly well documented. If you are going to use CodeIgniter then there are no excuses for not taking advantage of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For codeigniter

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at here  [http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/database/helpers.html](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html) and the first function is `$this->db->insert_id();`

This also works with activerecord inserts.

or you can do

```
$last_insert_id = $this->db->call_function('insert_id');
```